# Ubuntu para Win10 no se instala donde dicen

Tags: ubuntu, bash, windows10

Saludos,

Quería saber qué otro sitio se instala el Bash para Windwos 10 ya que AppData/Local/lxss no existe y el Bash me está funcionando perfectamente.

Comparto una imagen ya que valdrá más que 1000 palabras...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Carlos, bienvenido a SOes. Si "el bash" te esta funcionando perfectamente, ¿cual es el problema que quieres que te ayudemos a resolver? Tambien te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y ver el articulo: [ask], para entender mejor el funcionamiento de este sitio.

Comment: ¿Por qué marcaste como aceptada una respuesta que, por tu propio comentario, parece que no te valió? Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio. También lee [answer], donde encontrarás consejos y recomendaciones para mejorar tus respuestas.

Comment: En mi equipo está aqui, es posible que te de una pista :`C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-lxss-bash_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.351_none_79648c7a5a883c6f\bash.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahí es donde guarda los archivos que descargo. Dentro de "packages", no entiendo por qué en mi caso está ejecutandose en ese lugar, todo lo que he encontrado apunta a la famosa carpeta "lxss":

C:\Usuarios\cdiaz\AppData\Local\Packages

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya está recuperada, Carlos. Intenta añadir más información si puedes.  Un saludo

Answer (score -1):

AppData si exixte en todos los ordenadores con windows, solo que hay que saber buscarlo. Para ello en el explorador de archivos busca esto C:\Users\Pon_tu_usuario_Aquí\AppData\Local y ya estas en la carpeta

Comment: No existe, ya he estré antes, por eso publiqué ésta entrada, ya que dicha carpeta del Bash de Windows 10, no existe en mi sistema, no la encuentro por ningún lado. Es decir, "lxss" no está, no la veo...